# iMac Fan runs fast and hard

Tags: imac

Is it common for an imac fan to kick into full swing when booting up and never idling down even after 10 minutes? It sounds like a vacuum.

Would going in to the BIOS(no idea how to do that on a mac) and resetting help solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not normal. I had the same problem with an iMac a few years back and had to have the logic board replaced (under warranty thankfully).

You might have a SMC (System Management Controller) problem. This article explains how to reset it: 
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

You might also look at a tool like iStat Menus:
http://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/

What I found with iStat was that my CPU was running extra hot, hence the extra fan speed.

I did end up using an app called SMC Fan Control to mitigate the problem before getting the logic board replaced.